# Django url dispatcher not identifying the view

Tags: django, url-routing, django-urls, url-pattern

Here is my urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^volunteer/$', views.volunteerInformation, name='volunteerInformation'),
    url(r'^volunteer/(?P<ID>[0-0]{1})/$', views.volunteerInformation, name='volunteerInformation'),
]
```

Here is the view that I'm trying to call

```
def volunteerInformation(request, ID=None):
    volunteers = Volunteer.objects.all()
    if ID:
        print ID
    else:
        print "XKCD"
    return render(request, 'dbaccess/volunteer.html', {'volunteers': volunteers})
```

When the url is .../volunteer/, it prints XKCD. But when the url is ..../volunteer/1, I'm getting an error that the page was not found. Here is the error:

```
^ ^volunteer/(?P<ID>[0-0]{1})/$ [name='indVolunteerInformation']
^ ^volunteer/$ [name='volunteerInformation']
^admin/
The current URL, volunteer/3, didn't match any of these.
```

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url regex is wrong, you are searching for numbers of length 1 in the range 0-0. To match any number change this:

```
^volunteer/(?P<ID>[0-0]{1})/$
```

for something like

```
^volunteer/(?P<ID>\d+)/$
```